# SSL connection error from SQL server in Websphere

Tags: sql-server, ssl, websphere, ssl-certificate

WE are connecting to SQL server from our WAS(websphere). Connection is fine before we made the data present in SQL server encrypted and made the connection as SSL. From that onwards, we are getting SSL connection error. BUt we had installed the certificates under trusted key store in WAS console. Below is the error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: [IBM][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The SQL Server login requires an SSL connection.DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = 0*

*RAD version is 7.5.5
WAS version is Websphere Application Server 6.1*

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved by installing SQL server drivers in WAS console. Not sure how it worked before encryption without drivers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSL configured correctly, then I'm not sure what the following portion of the error mean:

```
The SQL Server login requires an SSL connection.DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = 0
```

A StaleConnectionException is explained in the IBM link below:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21063645

Perhaps if you paste the entire error stack we can see more clues. Is there a 'caused-by' clause for example? If this issue only occurred right after you have enabled SSL then you would also want to make sure both parties have common cipher suites.

Comment: Hi, I copied the error from "Caused By" Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: [IBM][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The SQL Server login requires an SSL connection.DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = 0

Comment: Ok, so the JDBC driver is telling us that the server requires SSL, which means for some reason the connection you're making is not being made using SSL protocol. Can you paste the entire error stack?

Comment: Hi Fateem, Thanks for the replies. Thats the entire error stack I can get from logs.

Comment: What version of Microsoft SQL Server are you using and what's the JDBC driver version?